# Where is my Rails application saving data if heroku pg output says zero tables?

Tags: database, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku

I created my first Rails application and it had a :dev: database for free. I paid $50 for a Crane database and deleted my dev database.

Running `heroku pg` command:

```
=== HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_NAVY_URL
Plan:        Crane
Status:      available
Data Size:   5.9 MB
Tables:      0
PG Version:  9.1.6
Connections: 3
Fork/Follow: Available
Created:     2012-12-17 21:46 UTC
Maintenance: not required
```

What's strange is that if I run `heroku run rake db:migrate` it runs fine, but `heroku pg` **still** shows 0 table count and the data in the app itself shows old data that was in my :dev: database.

Any suggestions? How can I tell Heroku, `Please use this database as the default from now on?`

Also, if `heroku pg` only shows 1 database, and that database has zero tables, where is my application getting the data it's currently displaying?

Comment: The table count and other stats might be cached. Have a look in your app (possibly via the Rails console: `heroku run console`) to see if the migrations happened as they should.

Comment: BTW: Heroku databases are charged by the minute or second, so you won't need to pay $50 upfront.

Comment: @ThomasKlemm: What command can I run to check tables that exist in `DATABASE_URL` when inside the heroku console?

Comment: Do anything related to a model, like counting: `User.count` etc. Rails will scream if the tables do not exist. :-D

Comment: @ThomasKlemm: I was thinking about a way to list the tables instead of checking one Model at a time.

Comment: I've never worked with the postgres console `psql` before but I just looked it up: You can run `heroku pg:psql` to enter the postgres console and there `\d+` to get some information on your tables. More commands [in this blog post](http://www.linuxscrew.com/2009/07/03/postgresql-show-tables-show-databases-show-columns/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, I had to promote my Crane database as the default database my Rails app will use. Rails apps on Heroku use the connection string named `DATABASE_URL`.

So first, I ran this command to get the name of the database I needed to promote:

```
heroku pg

=== HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_NAVY_URL
Plan:        Crane
Status:      available
Data Size:   5.9 MB
Tables:      0
PG Version:  9.1.6
Connections: 3
Fork/Follow: Available
Created:     2012-12-17 21:46 UTC
Maintenance: not required
```

Then I ran the promote command:

```
heroku pg:promote HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_NAVY_URL
```

Finally, since this is the default database now, I could run the migration against my Crane database:

```
heroku run rake db:migrate
```